# Error expected declaration on var declaration

Tags: swift, string, uitextfield

```
@IBOutlet var operateur : UITextField!
var nbOperateur : String?
nbOperateur = operateur.text
```

I can't understand why it is "Expected Declaration" , operateur can be only "+" or "-" or "%" or "x" or "/" , please I need help , thanks .

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error, so could you please elaborate by giving some more code/context.

Comment: Compare [How to initialize properties that depend on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other) or [Swift: expected declaration error setting “Label” to a string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764266/swift-expected-declaration-error-setting-label-to-a-string-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use  [`lazy var`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

```
 @IBOutlet var operateur : UITextField!
    lazy var nbOperateur : String = {
        self.nbOperateur = self.operateur.text ?? ""
        return self.nbOperateur
    }()
```

Comment: Don't use force unwrapping on a `UITextField.text` value, since there is a real probability that it will be `nil`.